# Comma with explanatory insertions?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I wonder if there should be commas in this sentence:

1. Method A translates votes into seats such that, for each
   constituency, fixed seat-contingents are met.
2. Method A translates votes into seats such that for each
   constituency fixed seat-contingents are met.

The expression "for each constituency" is not exactly parenthetical, but without the commas it seems harder to grasp the sentence.

Comment: I don't really understand what the sentence is supposedly saying (in either case). I'm guessing that perhaps switching _such that_ to _so that_ (or _in such a way that_) might clarify.  From dictionary.com: **such that**
_adj : of a degree or quality specified (by the `that' clause); their anxiety was such that they could not sleep_ : so the 'such that' introduces an adjectival modifying _anxiety_ here. I don't think the intention is to modify 'seats' above - but rather, the adequacy of 'Method A'.

Comment: "for each constituency" is **indeed** parenthetical, I think. "Method A translates votes into seats such that fixed seat-contingents are met." is a correct and complete sentence conveying part of the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the commas are necessary. Their function is not always to indicate that the information between them is parenthetical (and, therefore, unimportant). Sometimes their only function is to tell the reader to pause for half a second.

I agree with your assessment that without the commas, the sentence is more difficult to understand. Therefore, they are necessary. You're right.

Comment: +1. Agree. _For each constituency_ is, in R L Trask's term, a 'weak interruption'
http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node13.html#SECTION00044000000000000000

Comment: @Barrie: Yes, a weak interruption is a good term for this kind of added information. This term is helpful.